# The use of the word "early"

Tags: word-usage

can I use the word "early" referring to "old"?

for example :

the early means of travelling were hard.

what I mean here is that the means of travelling in past were hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of.

'Early' in this context means 'the oldest', rather than just 'old'.

You could say that *early* mobile phones were very large, you could also say some *old* mobile phones have touch screens, but you could **not** say some *early* mobile phones had touch screens, as touch screen mobiles phones are too *late* to be *early*.

> The early means of travelling were hard.

would refer to just walking, and possibly horse, or ox driven carts and the like, it would *not* refer to steam trains, or even hansom cabs (19th century horse-drawn vehicle).